# How to use the funset_avltree library?

Tags: compiler-errors, code-generation, ats

I am trying to use the `funset_avltree` library, but the compiler generates invalid C code. I am using ATS/Postiats version 0.2.10.

My code is fairly straightforward:

```
(* ast.sats *)
staload "libats/SATS/funset_avltree.sats"

datatype ast =
  | ast_var of string

fun free_vars (ast : ast) :<> set string
```

```
(* ast.dats *)
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
staload "./ast.sats"
staload "libats/SATS/funset_avltree.sats"
dynload "libats/DATS/funset_avltree.dats"

implement free_vars (ast : ast) : set string =
  case+ ast of
  | ast_var name => funset_sing name
```

The compiler output, however, is rather confusing:

```
ast_dats.c:359:51: warning: implicit declaration of function 'S2EVar' is invalid
      in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
ATSINSmove(tmpret0, PMVtmpltcstmat[0](funset_sing<S2EVar(4713)>)(tmp1)) ;
                                                  ^

ast_dats.c:359:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'funset_sing'
ATSINSmove(tmpret0, PMVtmpltcstmat[0](funset_sing<S2EVar(4713)>)(tmp1)) ;
                                      ^

ast_dats.c:359:64: error: expected expression
ATSINSmove(tmpret0, PMVtmpltcstmat[0](funset_sing<S2EVar(4713)>)(tmp1)) ;
                                                               ^
```

I get similar errors with `funset` and `funset_listord`. I must be missing something trivial. Do I need to include something or pass some flag to the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the root cause is you didn't statically load AVL tree templates provided by the library.

In the error message, `PMVtmpltcstmat` usually indicates something is wrong with templates. It is usually the case that programmers forget to include the templates, or forget to supply template variables. You are the first case.

Please add this line,

```
staload _ = "libats/DATS/funset_avltree.dats"
```

to statically load templates, and make them available to the compiler. See an working example here, https://glot.io/snippets/eiu6f3dd2r

---

Besides, `dynload` is needed when you have "global" values that needs evaluation. In your case, you do not need to `dynload` the avl tree library. Also, in your own file `ast.dats`, there is no such global value. You can define

```
#define ATS_DYNLOADFLAG 0
```

to tell compiler not to generate dynamic loading code for `ast.dats`.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I didn't know you had to staload dats files with template definitions. I couldn't find this in the book "Introduction to Programming in ATS".

Comment: You're welcome. The template system is fairly new. I think the author is still finishing relevant chapters.

Comment: @rightfold, I visited your site. It is really nice that you keep a documentation about ATS. I just want to bring to your attention that http://discourse.ats-lang.org/c/documentation is official and is planned to include more and more user contributed documentations. And your contribution is very welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in ATSLIB:

https://github.com/githwxi/ATS-Postiats/blob/master/libats/ML/HATS/myfunset.hats

There is a chapter on functional sets and maps in the following
book:

http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/ATS2TUTORIAL/HTML/HTMLTOC/book1.html

It is currently Chapter 12:

http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/ATS2TUTORIAL/HTML/HTMLTOC/c514.html